# Coldfusion/Javascript if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I could really use some help on this one. I am modifying someone elses code. Bassically what the script does is it Loops through data via coldfusion. The user is suppose to insert data into each of these looped items. Then once completed the javascript box pops up and confirms the data that the user has entered is correct. This works fine... The part I am having trouble with is I need a check box next to each looped form that they click to select which looped form they want to submit. I've gotten the coldfusion part to work easily.. However, I need the verification box to ONLY verify the forms that have been checked.

Confirmation Box Varibles Exaple

```
<cfset VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] = VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] & "<br /><br /><strong>LEASE:</strong>&nbsp;">
                    <cfset VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] = VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] & "L. HRS: <strong style=""color:black"">' + $('##LE_LEFH#CurrentRow#').val() + '</strong>">
                    <cfset VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] = VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] & "&nbsp;|&nbsp;L. CYCLES: <strong style=""color:black"">' + $('##LE_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#').val() + '</strong>">
                    <cfset VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] = VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] & "&nbsp;|&nbsp;R. HRS: <strong style=""color:black"">' + $('##LE_REFH#CurrentRow#').val() + '</strong>">
                    <cfset VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] = VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] & "&nbsp;|&nbsp;L. CYCLES: <strong style=""color:black"">' + $('##LE_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#').val() + '</strong>">
                    <cfset VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] = VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & CurrentRow] & "<br /><br />">
```

Checkbox Example

```
<div style="color:##ff0000;background-color:;background-color:##dadada;border-left:1px solid ##999;border-right:1px solid ##999;border-bottom:1px solid ##999;"><input type="Checkbox" name="Confirm#CurrentRow#" value="1"> <strong>Select to report engine usage for this aircraft.</strong></div></div>
```

The Confirmation Box Action Code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // catch submit 
      $("##btn_submit").click(function(e){
        jConfirm('<strong>Confirm your engine usage information. Click Confirm to proceed or Edit to edit your values.</strong><cfloop from="1" to="10" index="x">#VARIABLES["PromptMessage" & x]#</cfloop><br />', 'Report Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
          // If they confirmed, manually trigger a form submission
          if (r) $("##btn_submit").parents("FORM").submit();
        });
        // Always return false here since we don't know what jConfirm is going to do
        return false;
      });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('This dialog will show every time!')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Basic Dialog',
        modal: true,
        height: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

$('##popup').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
});
});

 </script>
```

Just keep in mind that it's looping thorugh a query.

Comment: What have you tried? I looked over your code twice to see where you might have attempted to solve this, but I just can't find it. Forgive me if I'm overlooking it. For instance, you haven't even given your checkbox an ID or class for jQuery to reference.

Comment: @DavidThomas that's an escape character in ColdFusion. Variables are referenced by `#` such as `#variablename#`.

Comment: @CoderSeven I'm not the best with javascript. I actually avoid it like the plauge. Coldfusion has AJAX built in that I use and that's all I ever use. The reason behind this is that we deal with a lot of corporate clients which normally have javascript turned off on their browsers.

Comment: @FuelieNetworks They are using jQuery here, which is an extension/mod/plugin/library to Javascript that makes everything wonderfully easy. [link1](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) [link2](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) The documentation is great. Don't be afraid of Javascript, this isn't 1998. Javascript is your friend. jQuery is when your friend brings the beer. :)

Comment: Not to mention the Ajax stuff in cf just writes js to the client for you. Some homegrown but mostly extjs library so your attempt to avoid js and the assumption that js is disabled is faulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you redesign your form.  Instead of this marrying everything to the row number of the query, marry them to the id field of the record.  They'll be easier to work with that way.

The checkboxes will be easier to work with if they all have the same name but different values.  Something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="somequery">
<input type="checkbox" name="processme" value="#id#">
</cfoutput>
```

Then, when you process the form you can do a simple loop.

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "processme")>
<cfloop list = "#form.processme#" index="ThisID">
code
closing tags
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar to this. I basically selected the aircraft I wanted.. Had that refresh the page and rerunning the query with only the aircraft selected.. then had the javascript pop up come up automatically on the new page. This simulated a pop up on submit and only allowing the selected aircrafts to come up and populating the popup.